# Diophantine equation with a prime number

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $m,n$ are integers and $p$ is a prime number. Find $(p,n,m)$ if $m^2-3mn+n^2p^2 = 12p$.

I have tried to use the quadratic formula on m,n,p but the three turned to be really messy. Also I tried to factor and take advantage of the fact $p$ is prime but that didn't really help.

Comment: **Hint:** $4p-mn$ must be a multiple of $3$. And so must *m* and $np$.

Answer (score 2):

Since we have
$$m^2-3nm+n^2p^2-12p=0,$$
we have
$$D=(-3n)^2-4\cdot 1\cdot (n^2p^2-12p)\ge 0\Rightarrow n^2\le \frac{48p}{4p^2-9}\le \frac{48\cdot 2}{4\cdot 2^2-9}=\frac{96}{7},$$
which leads that $|n|=0,1,2,3.$ Here, note that $48p/(4p^2-9)$ is decreasing for $p\ge 2$.

Also, note that  for $n\not =0$,
$$4n^2p^2-48p-9n^2\le 0\Rightarrow 2\le p\le \frac{24+\sqrt{24^2+36n^4}}{4n^2}.$$

For $n=0$, $m^2=2^2\cdot 3p$ leads $p=3,m=6$.

For $n=\pm 1$, we have  $$2\le p\le \frac{24+\sqrt{24^2+36}}{4}\lt 12.2\Rightarrow p=2,3,5,7,11.$$
Hence, by checking each case, we know that there is no such integer $m$.

For $n=\pm 2$, we have $$2\le p\le \frac{24+\sqrt{24^2+36\cdot 2^4}}{4\cdot 2^2}\lt 3.63\Rightarrow p=2,3.$$
Hence, we have $(p,n,m)=(3,2,0),(3,2,6),(3,-2,0),(3,-2,-6).$

For $n=\pm 3$, we have $$2\le p\le \frac{24+\sqrt{24^2+36\cdot 3^4}}{4\cdot 3^2}\lt 2.31\Rightarrow p=2.$$
Hence, by checking each case, we know that there is no such integer $m$.

Hence, the answer is $(p,n,m)=(3,0,6),(3,2,0),(3,2,6),(3,-2,0),(3,-2,-6).$